# Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am using Spring rest Template to hit POST API and which is working absolutely fine.

The issue is when I am using it with MockRestServiceServer.

I have created one MockRestServiceServer instance :

```
mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
```

and added expected request URL and response i,e :

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo(URL)).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
    .andRespond(withSuccess(Response,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

When I am trying to hit specific POST URL with JSON body as

```
{"AppName":{"Value":"Google"}}
```

I am getting error as

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting double-quote 
to start field name  at 
[Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5473b9e; line: 1, column: 3]; 
nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character 
('A' (code 65)): was expecting double-quote to start field name  at 
[Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5473b9e; line: 1, column: 3]  at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal
(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:127) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]    
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:81) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]    
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]   
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]     
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:279) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

can anyone help me What I am missing here ??

Comment: Are you sure you send "AppName" and not just AppName. That's what the error suggests

Comment: Yes I am very sure the JSON is right. If i hit directly to restTemplate without MockServer I am getting the proper response but when I am trying with MockServer I get the above error logs.